# Add Header to tableview in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, scroll

I want to add header to tableview & not to sections in swift.I have class which is sub class of UITableViewController. I want to keep header part fixed & other part scrollable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how the header works in a table view. You can create a header for the whole table (as opposed to a per-section title) using the `tableHeaderView` property; but if you want to have a widget that is always displayed on screen you're better off creating another view controller to which you add the table as a child view.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been tableHeaderView.

Answer (score 13):

If you want the Header and not section headers than this is the way to do it:

```
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = 'your_value' ;// Here goes the UIView for the header
```

Answer (score 0):

Just drag a label on TableView before the cell ,note that you have to drag label on TableView  not in cell and give you title . thats it . your header is created .run and see the result .

Comment: this the same what @Steelzeh suggested.only difference is here you can do it with storyboard too. But this is not the answer the question asked.I should read question more carefully. 'AlBlue' has already given answer.